# What is tensile stress/force? Where should it be applied?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, elasticity, stress-strain

I am practicing questions from the topic elasticity.
There was a question from the book I.E. Irodov, Q.no)1.291.

The question is as follows:

What internal pressure(in the absence of an external pressure) can be sustained by a glass spherical flask, the wall thickness $\Delta$r = 1.0mm and the radius of flask equals r = 25mm?

When I referred the solution to this question, it read as follows:

Force due to pressure is F = p$\pi$$r^2$

For equilibrium, tensile force(T) = F,

And then the solution continued. Now comes my real doubt what is tensile stress/force, why are they equating it with force due to pressure, where should it be used?? (Ex. Pseudo force is used when the observer is in non-inertial frame).

Comment: Pseudo force is related to dynamics, and the above problem is strictly statics.

Comment: @JAlex Yea, I just used it as an example... Just so the reader can be clear what I am asking about.

Comment: @Srini - Hi. Welcome to SE. Just as a reminder, if an answer solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution you could accept it by clicking on the checkmark.

Comment: @SG8 - Oh thanks, just now came to know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a small element on the surface of the sphere ${\rm d}A$ and perform static analysis by balancing the forces.

"Tensile" force is the the force exerted by the sphere to the surroundings as a result of deformation. A better term would be radial force, or even better it should not talk about forces at all but stresses.

So if the radial stress is $\sigma_r$ then the "Tensile" force is ${\rm d} F_r = \sigma_r\, {\rm d}A$ as developed right under the skin.

Over the skin of the sphere the pressure force is ${\rm d}F_p = P\, {\rm d}A$

the force balance ${\rm d}F_r = {\rm d}F_p$ yields the boundary condition for the stress field

$$ \sigma_r = P $$

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

They are splitting the sphere into a hemisphere, and balancing forces normal to the flat split.  The resultant force of pressure on the hemisphere is $\pi r^2 p$.  The tensile force on the glass is $2\pi r\Delta r\sigma$, where $\sigma$ is the tensile stress in the glass in the hoop direction.  So $$2\pi r\Delta r\sigma=\pi r^2 p$$or$$\sigma=\frac{pr}{2\Delta r}$$